# MUI Drawer should be below header component with Fixed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have Following Component :

```
Header.js

<header className="header"> 
 //to be rendered
</header>

.header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 5rem;
   display: flex;
}

<main className="main-view">
   <aside className="main-view__navigation">
     <NavigationDrawer
        handleIsCollapsed={handleIsCollapsed}
        isCollapsed={isCollapsed}
      />
  </aside>
 <Outlet />
```

.main-view {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
    
      &__navigation {
        position: relative;
      }
    }

```
NavigationDrawer.jsx :

    const Drawer = styled(Drawer, {
      shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open",
    })(({ theme, open }) => {
      return {
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        boxSizing: "border-box",
        height: "100%",
        boxShadow: `0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0px 5px 5px -3px #00000033,
        0px 8px 10px 1px #00000024`,
        backgroundColor: palette.papergray,
        ...(open && {
          ...openedNav(theme, drawerWidth),
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": openedNav(theme),
        }),
        ...(!open && {
          ...closedNav(theme),
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": closedNav(theme),
        }),
      };
    });

Main -

<>
  <Header />
  <main className="main-view">
    <aside className="main-view__navigation">
      <NavigationDrawer
        handleIsCollapsed={handleIsCollapsed}
        isCollapsed={isCollapsed}
      />
    </aside>
    <Outlet />
  </main>
  <Footer />
</>
```

Here I am not able to fix my header and the drawer component as when I apply the `position-fixed` to the header then some content goes up and then Drawer component has the z-index which goes above.Is there anyway through which I can fix this. ?